# Can't access Javascript object from C# (CefSharp)

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

My setup is really simple, in C# (WPF) I have a WebView, that loads my HTML page.

Now I want to have a two way communication between the two.

Calling C# from Javascript works totally fine for me, using `RegisterJsObject`.

Now I try to execute Javascript from C#, using `ExecuteScript`.

As long as I only use plain Javascript, such as

```
ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='test'")</code>
```

it works perfectly fine.

But when I try to access functions I created in Javascript, it fails to execute them.

**Javascript:**

```
function test(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

**C#:**

```
webView.ExecuteScript("test('123')");
```

Comment: Which version of CefSharp are you using? I think latest stable has a slightly different syntax. Are you sure the function is loaded when you call it? I guess you should be able to check from your C# with something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Example:_Determining_whether_a_function_exists

Comment: Here is an experience with the [CefSharp 31 -pre1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/cefsharp/IbbgXnOiNV8) release. I was able to replicate both the good and bad case back then... At least now you have something to compare with.

Comment: I got the latest CefSharp package using NuGet.
I started my project again from scratch, building very basic scenarios first before getting more complicated, and now I got it magically to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what my actual problem was.

I got it to work by starting from scratch again, starting with basic calls, then getting closer to the actual code I want to execute, and now it somehow works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I invoke my Javascript function from my WPF C# application using a WebView:

```
 this.webView.InvokeScript("test", new object[] { "('123')" });
```

For a more detailed explanation go to this web site: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/840/working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf

Hope this is the answer that will help you.

Comment: I saw InvokeScript a lot on the web, but it is only available for WebBrowser and not for WebView.